# Failed to start Git process in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to push to github on Android Studio and I have this error. Push failed: Failed with error: Failed to start Git process. In my settings, the path to git executable tests fine, as does my login for Github. I tried setting the SSH to both native and built-in. I have no idea why I am unable to start the git process through Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the same on Windows, check you have Git installed and that the program directory is in your PATH environment variable.